# Is it possible to bind a shortcut to a button / function of an Office add-in?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I have implemented a button in my Office (Excel) add-in; clicking on the button will trigger a JavaScript function.

Does anyone know if it is possible to bind a keyboard shortcut to the button (or the function)? As a result, once users load the add-in, they could also use the keyboard shortcut to trigger the button / function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts are not currently possible, though you can certainly add it as a suggestion on our UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

That said, if you are using Add-in Commands which allow you to add buttons to the ribbon (https://blogs.office.com/2015/09/28/whats-new-in-office-2016-for-developers/), a user can right-click on the button and add it to their Quick Access Toolbar.

Adding the button:

[image]

Using the button from the Quick Access Toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Michael... If you still have to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354109/duplicate-event-handlers) before the weekend, that will help me a lot... that really puzzles me...

Comment: In addition, the user can press Alt to see keyboard shortcuts for any ribbon buttons, including those that are part of add-ins.